# Register behaving like latch in verilog

Tags: verilog, register

I have the following block of code -

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) 
        oe_hold <= 1'b0;
    else begin
         oe_hold <= 1'b0;
         if (oe && (oe_hold | we)) 
             oe_hold <= 1'b1;
    end
end
```

In the above fragment, `oe` and `we` are driven using combinational logic. I'd expect that if oe_hold and `oe` are **high**, at clock edge 0 and `oe` goes low at t=1, then oe_hold would go low at t=2, since oe_hold is a register and should take on its input a cycle later.

However, in simulation, oe_hold behaves like a latch. It goes low at the same clock edge as oe. If I drive `oe` on the negative edge in the testbench, oe_hold goes low on the following clock edge (i.e., the same edge it went low were `oe` driven on the positive edge).

Can someone explain this behavior and tell me why it occurs?

Thank you.

Update 1: `oe` is an input to the device under test and is set like so -

```
@ (posedge clk) begin
    oe = 0;
end
```

Update 2: [image]

Update 3: iverilog was used as the simulation tool.

Comment: In your code, `oe_hold` gets 0 for every input combination. So I'd expect it to go low whenever there is a clock rising edge.

Comment: @ThePhoton, that was a typographic error. Fixed. My apologies.

Comment: Please show the logic driving `oe`. My guess is `oe` is assigned with a blocking assignment.

Comment: A waveform would be nice ...

Comment: What happens if you replace ```oe = 1'b0``` with ```oe <= 1'b0```? I can only assume it is an issue with the simulator as if you synthesize it you get a clocked register as expected.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, that fixed it. However, I had to change every instance of all assignments to non-blocking, for some reason. Simply changing the assignments to oe did not change anything. For anyone wanting to know the entire solution, basically I have everything on the posedge in the testbench and all assignments (except for the initials) be non-blocking.

Comment: @maverick1989 clearly an issue with the simulator you are using. Although to be honest you should really stick to non-blocking assignments in Verilog unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause though as far as I can tell from what you have posted comes down to the way you are simulating the code. It would be good if you posted the code you used for simulation.

It is entirely possible that if you are using something like blocking statements to generate both the `oe` signal and `clk` signals in a testbench setup that the simulator gets confused and deasserts `oe` a very short amount of time before the rising edge of the clock which you wouldn't necessarily be able to see on a waveform view (it would look like it was changed on the clock edge), but would (in an RTL simulation at least) result in the behaviour you are seeing.

In practice it wouldn't happen as all the logic including the `oe` signal would be synchronous.

---

I'm going to post this bit as part of my answer rather than a comment as it allows better code formatting, but consider this alternative arrangement:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        oe_hold <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
         if (oe && (oe_hold | we)) begin 
             oe_hold <= 1'b1;
         end else begin
             oe_hold <= 1'b0;
         end
    end
end
```

Notice how now rather than trying to set oe_hold to \$0\$, then at the same time (non-blocking!) trying to set it to a \$1\$ if the conditional was true. Now it specifically sets it to \$0\$ only if it wasn't true. The if/else is of course equivalent to simply: `oe_hold <= (oe && (oe_hold | we));`.

This may or may not help with the issue depending on how your simulation software handles the conflicting assignment of your code. In practice it seems to synthesize to the same thing (in Quartus II at least), but I have seen odd behaviour from some simulators getting confused with certain constructs.

<sub>Note: I added some extra `begin`/`end` statements, though that was only to improve readability.</sub>

---

I also want to pick up on something in your question, you mentioned driving one signal on one clock edge and another on the opposite clock edge. In synchronous logic you should try to avoid this as it can lead to timing issues in the design - you basically make all your setup requirements twice as stringent (because the effective clock frequency is doubled!). Everything in a synchronous circuit should be clocked on the same edge.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately, the block of code you showed did not change the result. I am using iverilog which conforms to the 1995 standard. As such, the event queue should generate the if...else mux you show.

Comment: Re. timing, I only mentioned the negedge assignment because it was a way for me to check if oe_hold was being assigned combinationally. If that were the case, it would change state on the negedge along with oe, which did not happen. That lead me to believe it was behaving like a latch.